# Why as.numeric() is deleting ALL the decimals?

Tags: r

I have a set of values stored as character like this:

```
n <- c("209.0662", "133.0084", "407.0568", "306.0501", "332.1824", "191.0036", "151.026" , "243.0622")
```

I would like to convert them to numeric, but when I do, all the decimals disappear. Can someone help me understand how I can keep them?

```
n <- as.numeric(n)

>str(n) 
num [1:8] 209 133 407 306 332 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimals are still here.

```
> n <- c("209.0662", "133.0084", "407.0568", "306.0501", "332.1824", "191.0036", "151.026" , "243.0622")
> 
> n <- as.numeric(n)
> str(n)
 num [1:8] 209 133 407 306 332 ...
> n
[1] 209.0662 133.0084 407.0568 306.0501 332.1824 191.0036 151.0260 243.0622
```

The function `str` just has a different display.